# How to represent a superconformal algebra as differential operators acting on the fields in superspace?

Tags: supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, superconformality

Both super algebras and conformal algebras can be nicely represented as differential operators acting on the fields in superspace, but I've never seen one for superconformal algebras.

I would appreciate a general answer for all superconformal algebras, but my main interest is the 2d $\mathcal{N}=(2,2)$ case. The main obstacle for me seems to be how to represent the supercharges in the presence of $R$ charges.